# HTML input form to external link

Tags: html, button, search, input, tags

I am working on a new project and decided to do a lot of the coding myself, I am by no means a web developer but here we are :)

So....

I am coming towards the end of coding and just linking a few things up, I have WHMCS running on a vhost based external link and I need my domain search form to direct people from my main website to the vhost external link.

Here is the code I have so far...

```html
<form method="post" action="https://bill.spacesrv.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&" target="_blank" class="uk-form idz-search-domain-form">
        <fieldset>
                <input type="text" class="uk-form-large uk-width-1-1" name="query" value="" placeholder="find your perfect domain name">
                <button type="submit" class="uk-button-large idz-button blue uppercase">Find Domain</button>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have the domain in the action tag, I need that to stay the same and what the customer will search in the search box needs to go on the end of the domain.

This is what the final link should look like...

https://bill.spacesrv.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&query=domain.com

But currently when I hit the search button it is going to this link...

https://bill.spacesrv.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&

It is not adding the query={searched domain} to the end of the link.

Answer (score 0):

It is a WHMCS link which is open for the world to see anyway, its not a link that needs to be hidden.

Answer (score -1):

Nothwithstanding the fact that you need to take care of security ( dont open the target page for forms coming from *anywhere* ), you just need to specify the GET method for the form :

```
<form method="get" action="https://my.page.com?a=add" target="_blank" class="uk-form idz-search-domain-form">
```